# qlikview count items with an empty specific attribute

Tags: qlikview

I'm playing with personal edition of QV and can't figure one thing - I've taken export from Jira into excel and built charts and stuff and now I want to build a chart that will display count of jira items (that's "Count(Key)" in definition and works just fine) that have empty "time spent" (this I can't figure how to implement).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Count(If(not IsNull([Time Spent]), Key))